# Handling endianness of floating point values when there is no fixed size floating point type available

Tags: c++, floating-point, cross-platform, endianness, floating-point-conversion

I'm writing a binary file reader/writer and have decided that to handle the issue of endianness I will convert all data to **"network" (big) endianness on writing** and to **host endianness on reading**. I'm avoiding `hton*` because I don't want to link with winsock for just those functions.

My main point of confusion comes from how to handle floating point values. For all integral values I have the sized types in `<cstdint>` (`uint32_t`, etc.), but from my research no such equivalent exists for floating point types. I'd like to convert all floating point values to a 32 bit representation on writing and convert back to whatever precision is used on the host (32 bit is enough for my application). This way I will know precisely how many bytes to write and read for floating point values; as opposed to if I used `sizeof(float)` and `sizeof(float)` was different on the machine loading the file than the machine that wrote it.

I was just made aware of the possibility of using [`frexp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/frexp/) to get the mantissa and exponent in integer terms, writing those integers out (with some fixed size), then reading the integers in and reconstructing the floating point value using [`ldexp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ldexp/). This looks promising, but **I am wondering if there is any generally accepted or recommended method for handling float endianness without `htonf`/`ntohf`**.

I know with almost certainly any platform I'll be targeting anytime soon will have `float` represented with 32-bits, but I'd like to make the code I write now as compatible as I can for use in future projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be completely cross-platform and standards-compliant, then the `frexp`/`ldexp` solution is the best way to go. (Although you might need to consider the highly theoretical case where either the source or the target hardware uses decimal floating point.)

Suppose that one or the other machine did not have a 32-bit floating point representation. Then there is no datatype on that machine bit-compatible with a 32-bit floating pointer number, regardless of endianness. So there is then no standard way of converting the non-32-bit float to a transmittable 32-bit representation, or to convert the transmitted 32-bit representation to a native non-32-bit floating point number.

You could restrict your scope to machines which have a 32-bit floating point representation, but then you will need to assume that both machines have the same number and order of bits dedicated to sign, exponent and mantissa. That's likely to be the case, since IEEE-754 format is almost universal these days, but C++ does not insist on it and it is at least conceivable that there is a machine which implements 1/8/23-bit floating point numbers with the sign bit at the low-order end instead of the high-order end.

In short, endianness is only one of the possible incompatibilities between binary floating point formats. Reducing every floating point number to two integers, however, avoids having to deal with other incompatibilities (other than radix).